# File indexing in ruby

Tags: ruby, indexing

How do I index a medium size file in ruby, so that I don't have to parse the whole file everytime I want to find a specific line?

Comment: How would you index a file? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @UriAgassi He prob. whats to be able to search the file using something faster then O(n).

Comment: @UriAgassi See my answer below for an example.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if you feel it's correct or leave a comment for me to correct it. Thanks.

Comment: @UriAgassi, I edited the question. Is it OK now?

Comment: Hello @eendroroy, welcome to Stackoverflow, in order to write a clear question, you should describe the problem you are trying to solve, show us what you did so far, and  tell us what you were hoping to achieve. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to write better questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use sqlite3 with the [fts4](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) extensions to search through your file. Here I use an in memory database instead of a file, meaning that the database will be cleared every time you run it.

```
require "sqlite3"

your_file = "index.html"
db = SQLite3::Database.new(":memory:")

# Creates a table to store file in
db.execute("CREATE TABLE raw (body text);")

# Inserts file into db
stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO raw(body) VALUES(:body);") 
stmt.execute(body: File.read(your_file))
stmt.close

# Create a fulltext search table and import data from 'raw' table
db.execute("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE search USING fts4(body);")
db.execute("INSERT INTO search SELECT body FROM raw;")

# Search file
db.execute("SELECT body FROM search WHERE body MATCH 'google';") do |row|
  puts "Found #{row.first.length} chars"
end

db.close
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something similar.